# Rsync copy always the same files from MacOs to a server

Tags: macos, command-line, rsync

I have an external hd with a Macos extended journaled file system connected to my Macbook Air. I am trying to sync this external hdd to a server which is connected to the local network by Samba (Debian Buster Os). The server has its own hdd with a NTFS file system. Every time I lunch the command from the MacOs terminal

`sudo rsync -rvh --delete --dry-run --itemize-changes --modify-window=1 /sourcedir/ user@192.XXX.XXX.XXX:/destination/`

rsync plans to copy always all the files from the source to the destintion and not what is changed even with the option

`—modify-window=1`

is used.
All the files are quoted (option “—itemize-changes”) with

`f..T....`

Is there someone that can help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: It is not so simple to know, it will require some testing because of the different filesystems. I suggest you read this extensive topic about the same situation and maybe it can help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461283/why-modify-window-1-when-using-rsync-command

Comment: Prado, thank you very much for your comment. I have connected the external hdd to the server directly and I have just modified the file sistem types of the two server hdds (the external and the internal one): they are both ext4 right now. But if I connect to the server by ssh and lunched the rsync from my Mac, the problem remains. Why?

Comment: I don't know. have you tried rsync locally? You can do rsync between 2 local directories (without network).. What would be the result? This way we can eliminate the network portion, and check if it is a pure rsync application behaviour or other any filesystem behaviour. I would try it.